# SQL Server - Grabbing distinct values with two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good afternoon (it is here in Florida).

I have a table in SQL Server with the following data:

```
  id   StartDate     EndDate    
---- ------------ ------------ 
1   2015-06-30   2015-07-30  
2   2015-08-01   2015-08-31  
3   2015-08-01   2015-12-31  
4   2015-09-01   2015-09-30  
5   2015-10-01   2015-12-31
```

I need a 'distinct' select statement where I grab all but record 3, because it overlaps with another date.

What would be the best way to do this? I have tried Unions, but that isn't working.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: My expected output would need to look like this:

```
+============+============+
|     SD     |     ED     |
| 2015-06-30 | 2015-07-30 |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-08-01 | 2015-08-31 |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-30 |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-10-01 | 2015-12-31 |
+------------+------------+
```

I would want to exclude rows that have a date range that has a start date equal to another start date in the table as well as having an end date that makes that date range over lap with others. This is why row 3 should not be in the result set.

Thanks!

Comment: You should add to your question more rules on when rows should be excluded.  For example do you only consider it overlapping if two records have the same start date?  What if a date falls between the start and end date of another date range... which one is excluded?  Can there be chains of overlaps?

Comment: Along with what @BrianPressler said, your expected output would help.

Comment: @Khan *select statement where I grab all but record 3* so it's the records 1,2,4 and 5

Comment: Thank you, post has been edited!

Comment: Where does that first row in the expected results  come from?

Comment: I apologize, I grabbed an extra row from the data set. Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the shortest date range for every unique value of `StartDate`, then you can just use a group by on the `StartDate` and set the `EndDate` to the `Min`:

```
Select StartDate, Min(EndDate) EndDate
From TableDates
Group by StartDate
```

Comment: That is like too easy but it does what he said

Comment: Almost, I need to get rid of the 2015-08-01 / 2015-12-31 range, and keep 2015-08-01 / 2015-08-31

Comment: Then you want to use the Min aggregate function instead. (edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
    Select   a.Stard_Date as sd, min( a.End_date) as ed 
from tablename a group by a.Stard_Date
```